# If the `ffi` group of characters is smushed together into one character, then why I can select each of them separately?

Tags: unicode, characters, typography

In the video [Why You Can Tweet More In Japanese: What Counts As A Character?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sTzp76JXsoY), the author says that:

> Unicode has a single character for some English ligatures, like "ffi" - notice how the letters there are smushed together to make them look better to the eye. Some programs will automatically add those in for you. So you copy and paste your text from that into Twitter, and suddenly you're saving characters. People would count that as three characters. Unicode, and therefore Twitter, and pretty much every computer program? Just one.

But if so, then why can I still select each character separately?

[image]

Comment: The keywords are "some programs." These are not called "smushed letters", they are called ligatures. The prob;em with the quote is that is is technically true but mostly not true. There is silent ligature glyph replacement *for display* in some software, but by altering text with the unicode ligature it breaks it (the word is mispelled and/or no longer searchable).  Also, the rules arround ligatures are very complex so most software won't do it automatically. ( https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50660/when-should-i-not-use-a-ligature-in-english-typesetting )

Answer (score 2):

That's because you haven't copied the real character.

The real character is
[Unicode Character “ﬃ” (U+FB03)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+FB03)
and looks like:

```
ﬃ
```

You won't be able to select any sub-part of the above character,
only all of it.

Comment: hmm. Perhaps the actual question I'm aiming at is "why wouldn't my computer smush them together?" Should I edit the question now?

Comment: This would happen if your text-editor is not full Unicode.

Comment: except that editor is Firefox. It displays `ﬃ` (the smushed one) just fine, but doesn't automatically smush `ffi` (ffi)

Comment: Just tried Google in Firefox. I pasted the character and the selection is still all-or-nothing. Are you sure that the webpage you're pasting into is in Unicode and the character you paste is my above one?

Comment: @Ooker It's not up to the browser to do it, it's up to the site/app to do the replacement when the characters are input/saved (unless there is an extension installed that will add that functionality to the browser)

Comment: I test on Stack Exchange, YouTube, Wikipedia, Google. I can still select them separately in these sites

Comment: Try perhaps another browser or another copy-paste software. The character is being translated to its non-Unicode representation during this process or by the browser. You may use on Windows the [Free Clipboard Viewer](https://freeclipboardviewer.com/) (or another such app) to examine the contents of the clipboard.

Comment: I'm not sure why copy-paste software is involved here. Just to make sure that we are understanding each other, I'm talking about why the browser/site/app doesn't automatically convert `f-f-i` to `ﬃ` wherever the text containing them. It's like special characters are automatically escaped when HTML is rendering. Are we on the same page?

Comment: Apparently not. A sequence of ASCII character such as f,f,i is never automatically converted to Unicode, if that's the question. There are 149186 characters and 161 scripts in the latest Unicode standard, so if such a mechanism existed there would be an enormous problem with typing text into Unicode documents or webpages.